# force to show pdf in browser but idm download it.with laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

i want to show a pdf file inside browser but IDM download it before render start.

my Controller:

```
    public function pdf($user_id){
    $user = User::find($user_id);

    return view('profile')->with(['user'=>$user]);
    }
```

profile blade dive:

```
    <embed src="{{$user->pdf or null}}"
    type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px"/>
```

.htaccess file config added

```
     <Files ~ "\.(pdf)$">
       order deny,allow
       allow from all
     </Files>

    <FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
      ForceType application/octet-stream
      Header set Content-Disposition inline
      AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
    </FilesMatch>
```

I find 2 solution:
1:add the code to .htaccess file (BUT NOT WORK)

2:add header to response, and I dont know how i should send response to profile.blade and how use it in blade to show pdf.